# DNS and public WiFi portals

Tags: networking, dns

I use Ubuntu 17.10 and regularly encounter problems whilst connecting to public WiFi networks, especially those redirecting to a login portal.

When working on my personnal network, /etc/resolv.conf contains a nameserver pointing to 127.0.0.53, which (if I'm not mistaken) corresponds to the systemd-resolved service. And it works really well.

On a public Wifi, for some reason, this doesn't seem to help, and when trying to reach a page with Firefox, it loads for a long time before telling me it couldn't find the URL I gave it.

Right now, I figured this situation out by:

1. Setting `dns=none` in /etc/Networkmanager/Networkmanager.conf

   ```
   [main]
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
   dns=none

   [ifupdown]
   managed=false

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```
2. Disabling the systemd-resolved service: `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service`
3. Restarting network-manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`
4. Manually filling /etc/resolv.conf, I first need to enter the IP of the public router as nameserver. This loads the portal when entering the router's IP in Firefox. Then, I login.

   ```
   #Generated by NetworkManager
   nameserver 192.168.44.1
   ```
5. Edit /etc/resolv.conf back with public DNS adresses (usually 8.8.8.8)

   ```
   # Generated by NetworkManager
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.8.4
   ```

After this procedure, I never encountered any problems for the rest of the session, but I wanted to know if there was a not so painful way to fix this annyoing problem. I know dnsmasq exists, but didn't use it for a long time since it conflicted regularly with my university's VPN.

I've kind of figured out how Ubuntu (and Linux in general) work by myself every time a new problem appears since I installed it, so if you couldn't get too deep in technical details, I would appreciate! :)